# Why is my Microsoft Pinyin IME suddenly making traditional characters instead of simplified?

Tags: input-methods

I tried to type 什么, but I got 什麽! It was working just a minute ago.  What happened?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Simplified Chinese Microsoft Pinyin IME is capable of both simplified and traditional characters. When you install it, it will be set for simplified characters. It is set up to toggle between simplified and traditional with the keybinding <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. It is easy to do this accidentally if the IME is active and you do a "Find All" in Visual Studio or a similar program with the same keybinding.

You can toggle back by activating the IME (if necessary, using <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) and then toggling back with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

You can disable this key or change it to another letter (note, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> is not optional!) by navigating to the keyboard options:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and start typing "language" and select:

[image]

- Click on the language and it will expand and offer an "options" button:

[image]

- Now find the keyboards, click on the "Microsoft Pinyin" keyboard (probably the only one):

[image]

- **From there you can toggle back to simplified under "General" and modify the toggle binding at the bottom of "Keys"**

Answer (score 1):

Under General Pinyin style, the character set could be been set to Traditional chinese.
Switch to Simplified chinese from there. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered before but as of 08/12/2020, the simplified language pack can be switched to traditional either intentionally or not by pressing ctrl+shift+f and to stop your computer from doing this just do the following

Go to Language settings and click Options

[image]

and then click Microsoft Pinyin's Options button

[image]

Go to Keys

[image]

and then at the bottom you can disable this setting

[image]

This gave me a lot of headache as I needed to use simplified for my job.